chi-square test of independence - adjusted residuals interpretation
If you have a large contingency table (or variables with a lot of categories), should the relationship with the highest adjusted residual be interpreted as the combo that is informing the sig. chi-square test?
Since I have a lot of categories per variable it is often the case that 2-3 combos are approaching 1.96 threshold or exceed this value.

Why would you pick only one of them?
